# PHP - Slow performance on function return assignment

Tags: php, performance, function, variable-assignment

As part of a project i came across this situation where inside a loop, i store the value of a function return.
This happened to be a bottleneck for the application, where big arrays would take forever to be processed.

To me, the assignment should be no reason for the incredible slow performance.
On the other hand, the same function call, with no assign on return gives much better performance.

Can you explain me why the first loop is much slower?

`Output:
First took 1.750 sec.
Second took 0.003 sec.`

```
class one {

    private $var;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->var = array();
    }

    public function saveIteration($a) {     
        $this->var[] = $a;
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function getVar() {      
        return $this->var;      
    }
}

$one = new one();    
$time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $res = $one->saveIteration($i);
}    
echo "First took " . number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 3) . " sec.";

$time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $one->saveIteration($i);
}  

$res = $one->getVar();
echo "<br>Second took " . number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 3) . " sec.";
```

Comment: It isn't simply an assignment.... it's extending an array, that entails memory allocation (among other overheads)

Comment: @MarkBaker the array extension doesn't explain why the first loop is slower, because the extension occurs in both loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably have something to do with the fact that you're creating 10.000 arrays; each time incrementing the number of elements of the **new** array by 1 element.

My guess while you're inside the loop the local variable isn't freed on its own; Therefore I went ahead & tried freeing it using unset which got the results very close.

I know this is not a real world example; but in your code if you have something similar you could get away with it by just freeing (unsetting) the local variable once you're finished with it

here's your test code again:

```
class one {

    private $var;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->var = array();
    }

    public function saveIteration($a) {
        $this->var[] = $a;
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function getVar() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}

$one = new one();
$time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $res = $one->saveIteration($i);
    unset($res);
}
echo "First took " . number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 3) . " sec.".PHP_EOL;

$time_start = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $one->saveIteration($i);
}

$res = $one->getVar();
echo "Second took " . number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 3) . " sec.".PHP_EOL;
```

**Note:** the only thing I've modify is adding unset in the first example

**Result:**

- First took 0.068 sec.
- Second took 0.062 sec.

Comment: "*you're creating 10.000 arrays each time*"  Could you explain further?  When `$i` increments say from 0 to 1, how are 10,000 more arrays created?

Comment: My bad, I am missing a semicolon here I'll update the answer to avoid confusion

Comment: lol what a difference that makes.  Your observation is really interesting; thanks for sharing it. I don't get why `unset` should make such a huge difference. Afterall, if we overwrite the previous array with a new `$res =` assignment, and given that no other variable is referencing the previous array, shouldn't whatever resources it took be free? Shouldn't `unset` be redundant?

Comment: if you declare the variable $res before the loop, and unset  before the return, the code fills it's purpose and brings it back to similar performance.

    $res = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        unset($res);
        $res = $one->saveIteration($i);
    }

Comment: @ahmad Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#99660 the array return value is not passed by-reference but by-value. Which means that a copy of the array is created (at the very least, when you change it again), which in turn needs time to actually create the copy (allocate memory, memcopy the data).

Comment: Yup, this is it. You could forcibly return by reference but given this example, I don't know why you would

Comment: @PeterBailey especially since it's a private var. The example is artificial anyway, so the question is, why would this be a problem in the end ^^

Comment: @Jakumi It is a question of trying to understand my mistake, so i don't repeat it.
It seems to me (i am no expert), an absurd amount of time for internal copy operations.
Correct me if i'm wrong, with the unset tip of ahmad, looks like a case of bad memory management.

Answer (score 0):

@Jakumi made an excellent point. Since the values must be copied when you assign, 10,000 extra operations and a lot more memory are required in the first loop.

The difference between the two loops is actually much greater than your testing shows.  Your comparison would be more fair if between the two tests, you reset with:

```
unset($one); $one = new one();
```

In your current test, the second loop is being executed  while still holding the large array from the first loop in memory, so your results are not independent. See [this modification](https://3v4l.org/XCBuY)